# Twitter typeahead.js not initializing / working as expected using remote data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

Twitter typeahead not working as expected, when I comment out code in the library I do get a non-styled drop down of suggestions.

```
    jQuery('input#test').typeahead(
    {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        limit:25, //still using 5 which is default in the library
        minLength: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'customLookup',
        source: function(query, result) {
            return jQuery.ajax({
                url: url, //my dynamic url, returns custom json array that needs to be mapped
                data: 'shop_name=' + query + "&limit=25", //custom limit against backend api
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    var suggestions = [];
                    
                    jQuery.map(data.data, function(item){
                        suggestions.push(item.name + " - " + item.address);
                    });

                    result(suggestions); //stepping in, it just skips because syncCalled already = true? Then remove that code and it gives me back a list of 5 that isn't styled...

                    console.log(suggestions); //has array of strings as expected
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So are there options or updates I've missed capturing when configuring? Using a back end custom data source that needs JSON mapped to an array for typeahead.

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up modifying the library directly and having our own copy, not sure the issue but seems to work fine with that approach and using custom CSS to style.